# the meaning of 'catching mid-stride'

Tags: meaning

I guess it is similar to the word 'Halfway' in the following sentence,
A storm of arrows erupts from the walls, **catching you mid-stride**.
Am I right?

Comment: We're *slightly* more likely not to bother with the hyphen today. But what don't you understand about [the dictionary definition?](http://www.yourdictionary.com/midstride)

Answer (score 1):

The verb **catch** can have a very general abstract meaning of *incidence*. It can mean that something happens *coincident with* an event:

> The hunter took a shot with his rifle and caught the deer mid-leap.

The hunter's shot struck the deer just as it was leaping.

Or

> The uppercut caught him on the chin.

Knuckles and chin bone were in the same place at the same time.

Or:

> Sorry for the mess on my desk. You've caught me doing my taxes.

The person arrived just when the speaker filling out his tax forms.

Or:

> The photograph you took caught me mid-yawn.